# Sublime Text 4 LSP.pylsp not working with mypy or black

Tags: sublimetext4

I've got a Python project using poetry. After installing LSP and LSP-pylsp plugins in ST4, I don't manage mypy to work. Here are my override settings:

```
{
    "settings": {
       "pylsp.plugins.pylsp_mypy.enabled": true,
       "pylsp.plugins.pylsp_black.enabled": true
    },
    "command": [
        "/Users/maraujop/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/projecta-bW92pdzV-py3.9/bin/pylsp"
    ],
    "env": {
        "MYPYPATH": "/Users/maraujop/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/projecta-bW92pdzV-py3.9/bin/mypy"
    }
}
```

I've got several things installed in my poetry environment: mypy, black. I've managed to enable flake8 but that's it, the rest doesn't work. After setting `debug` in the plugin, I don't see anything in the console that tells me what's happening. Also I would be interested in running mypy with flag `--check-untyped-defs` and I'm not sure where to pass args.